# Importing .tex file in LaTeX

Tags: import

I am working on an econometric thesis, and I need to import my stata regression output to LaTeX. I have saved the results as a `.tex` file on my desktop, but the `\include` or `\import` commands don't seem to get the data into my LaTeX doc. Is there any alternate command that I should be using instead?

Comment: how do you use the commands?

Comment: Without much context we can't answer this well. Are you sure when using `\include{foo.tex}` the file `foo.tex` is in the root directory of your project folder?

Comment: What is the real data format of the saved file? Changing the file extension does not change the data format.

Comment: `\import` isn't provided by the LaTeX kernel (so you'd need to say which package you tried to use it with). If you simply want the contents of the `.tex` file inserted into the document, then `\input` is more appropriate than `\include`. (See [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include).) If your results file is on the desktop, are you trying to add the full path to it? (I'm guessing your document code isn't also on the desktop.) Do you get any error messages?

Comment: you should almost certainly be using `\input` not `\include` (assuming the file is in fact tex syntax)

Comment: You can write LaTeX in [Stata](http://www.stata.com/meeting/germany09/jann.pdf).
Or insert the command in latex or include a graphic from the stata report (like a print screen made with snap tool)

Answer (score 2):

According to your question, you have saved the regression results as a `.tex` file on your desktop. However, it is not clear if the result is Latex source code or another data representation. You must check what is the content of the file.

As mentioned by David Beauchemin, you can produce Latex files inside Stata using the `texdoc` module/command. You may check many websites and slides explaining how to produce latex content using that module.

- [in a page the Unibe website](http://repec.sowi.unibe.ch/stata/texdoc/)
- [in a paper of the Stata Journal](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0062)
- [in a working paper of the Universitat Bern](ftp://ftp.repec.org/opt/ReDIF/RePEc/bss/files/wp14/jann-2015-texdoc.pdf)

Once you have a file in Latex, you may "import" that file using `\input`. There is an [import latex module](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/import) that adds supports for the mentioned commands  `\import` and `\subimport`. However, if you are not creating very complex documents, you may import the file without using this module.

If you have a file in another format, you must find which it is. Depending on the format, you may find other Latex modules to include the content in your documents.